# Promise chaining and all

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have build this use case that I don't understand.

I want create an array of promises (var `array` in example) and add all the promises that resolve each element of the array.
Optionally, for some element of the array, I want make an extra elaboration so i chain another `Promise` (inside `if (e === 'b')`).

I will expect that the `Promise.all(array)` will catch the reject condition but it print:

```
> node .\test.js
b is ok
all clear
(node:1304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: 'b is ok' is NOT ok
```

Why this happen? The `Promise.all` don't manage the chaining?

The `thePromise` is pointing to a promise with another promise chained. I think that all `thePromise` chain need to be evaluated for consider it resolved, not only the first. Am I missing something?

I have notice that the practical solution is reassign the promise like this:

```
thePromise = thePromise.then((msg) => ....
```

The example code:

```
const array = [];
const arrayData = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

arrayData.forEach((e) => {
  let thePromise = newPromise(e);

  if (e === 'b') {
    thePromise.then((msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
      return newPromise(msg);
    });
  }

  array.push(thePromise);
});

Promise.all(array)
  .then(() => console.log('all clear'))
  .catch(err => console.log('something goes wrong', err));


function newPromise(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (value === 'b is ok') {
      reject(new Error(`'${value}' is NOT ok`));
    } else {
      resolve(`${value} is ok`);
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `Promise.all` don't manage the chaining?

Yes it did. It managed all the promises in the `array`, which all were fulfilled, that's why it logged `all clear`.

The `Promise.all` does not know - cannot know - about that new promise you created with `thePromise.then(…)`. It's not in the chain, it's branching away. And when it is rejected, nothing handles the error.

Comment: "branching" is the word that clarify me all!